# Why do some sources speak of the Sahasrara chakra and others of Saharara padma?

Tags: chakras

Some sources seem to use the term Saharara padma instead of Sahasrara chakra? Why do say do so? Do different traditions see the concept differently?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Sahasrara = 1000

Padma = Lotus

Sahasrara Chakra = Chakra with 1000 (Petals)

Sahasrara Padma = (Chakra) with 1000 Lotus Petals.

They are actually same thing.